# Cloudera Director Server AWS Quick Start

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloudera, cloudera-director

I am following the Cloudera AWS Quick Start

https://s3.amazonaws.com/quickstart-reference/cloudera/hadoop/latest/doc/Cloudera_EDH_on_AWS.pdf

I am using Option 2 Using Cloudera Director Server.  I start the server using ./bin/cloudera-director-server as instructed then I am prompted with "Listening for connections on port 7189".  I am unsure how to run the next step as there is no prompt.

./bin/cloudera-director bootstrap-remote aws.simple.conf --ip.remote.hostAndPort= 127.0.0.1:7189 ip.remote.username=admin --ip.remote.password=admin

Output

[ec2-user@ip-xx-x-x-xxx cloudera-director-server-1.1.0]$ ./bin/cloudera-director-server
Server logs can be found at /home/ec2-user/cloudera/cloudera-director-server-1.1.0/logs/application.log
Cloudera Director Server 1.1.0 initializing ...
Listening for connections on port 7189 on all interfaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `bin/cloudera-director` script starts the server in the foreground, which is why you don't see a prompt. Some choices for you:

- Run the `bin/cloudera-director bootstrap-remote` command in a separate shell session, or
- Use `bin/start` to start the server as a background process.

Also, in the bootstrap-remote command, the options must start with "lp" and not "ip".

Answer (score 0):

Additional pointers:

1. For step 4, please make sure to use the appropriate folders as highlighted below:
   /cloudera-director-client**-1.1.2**
   /cloudera-director-server**-1.1.2**
2. It was helpful to me to refer/copy the commands from the original post:
   https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/bigdata/post/Tx2D0J7QOVRJBRX/Deploying-Cloudera-s-Enterprise-Data-Hub-on-AWS